# Rails activerecord joins method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I want to find all the alsatians owned by friends of a given dog's owner.

Can you split a query up as in the following pseudo-code? (obviously `:owners = ...` does not work):

```
def self.get_alsatian_pals_of(the_dog)
  :owners = the_dog.owner.friends
  @alsatians = Dog.joins(:owners).where(dogs: {owner_id: :owners.id}).where(dogs: {breed: "alsatian"})
end
```

But you can see what I'm trying to do yes?

Question 1: How do you "re-submit" the collection from one query (`:owners`) into another query?

Question 2: There must be a "correct" way of doing this, all on one line. How would that look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def self.get_alsatian_pals_of(the_dog)
  owners = the_dog.owner.friends
  @alsatians = Dog.where(owner_id: owners.ids, breed: "alsatian")
end
```

Basically the mistake is here `:owners.id`, it should be `:owners.ids` and the `joins` statement is unnecessary.

Comment: @SRack `.ids` does work. 

`User.last.vehicles.limit(2).ids
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "vehicles"."id" FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 2]]
 => [8317, 8318] `

Comment: Ah, nice @Coco, thanks for the update - I really didn't think that existed, and didn't see it in the docs before posting my comment. You learn something new every day! I'll remove my existing comment, and a +1 for your answer :) Edit: aha, it be [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ids).